# Replace preg_replace through preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have a PHP library here and I want to replace `preg_replace` with `preg_replace_callback`.

This is the line:

```
preg_replace("/=([0-9A-F][0-9A-F])/e", 'chr(hexdec("$1"))', $l)
```

and this is what I did:

```
preg_replace_callback("/=([0-9A-F][0-9A-F])/", function($m) { return chr(hexdec($m["$1"])); }, $line);
```

But it didn't work. I still don't understand how `preg_replace_callback` works. I also looked into many other threads.

Can anyone help me please.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Replace `$m["$1"]` with `$m[1]`.

Comment: Do a print_r of your `$m` array in your callback function. You would see that the structure is wrong. `$m["$1"]` should most likely be `$m[1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$m[1]` to access the second element in the `$m` array:

```
preg_replace_callback("/=([0-9A-F][0-9A-F])/", function($m) { return  
    chr(hexdec($m[1])); }, $line
);
```

See [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/yuH1zw).

Comment: Why has your answer been marked as  "community wiki"?  Did you do that? or did someone else?  Please explain if it's not too much trouble.  (I just read a Meta post on community wiki, but I don't see the benefit.)